# how to change the default bin path of a node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, mean-stack, executable

I have a node module which is having windows batch files and executables but the folder doesn't have the permission for running those files, So i just wanted to **change the default "node_modules/.bin"** path and set an absolute path where I can copy my batch files and execute.